# Select second to last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i need to select the value of second to last input selectable element:

```
<tr><td><select class="x">...</select></td></tr>
<tr><td><select class="x">...</select></td></tr>
<tr><td><select class="x">...</select></td></tr>
```

The select input tag are inside tr tags.

If I use `$("select.x").last()`, jQuery select the last element. I need to select second to last.

Comment: You should use "penultimate" to be clearer. 2 to last coulb be interpreted as elements from 2 to N.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) with negative indexes:

```
$("select.x").eq(-2);
```

These negative indexes are "1-indexed": `-1` gives the last element, `-2` the penultimate, and so on.

Answer (score 13):

You can use .prev()

```
$("select.x").last().prev();
```

Answer (score 6):

All of the below will do the trick (select the second last element):

```
$("select.x").eq(select.length - 1)

$("select.x:nth-last-of-type(2)")

$("select.x:nth-last-child(2)")

$("select.x").last().prev()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector and move to the preceding element using [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$("select.x:last").prev();
```

Ref:

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Sample demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ck8XP/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "nth-last-child(2)" of jquery, this selects the second last element.

You can check this here:

https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

The solutions with .prev() or nth-last-child() don't works.

```
<tr><td><a>...</a><select class="x"></select><a>...</a><td><tr>
<tr><td><a>...</a><select class="x"></select><a>...</a><td><tr>
<tr><td><a>...</a><select class="x"></select><a>...</a><td><tr>
<tr><td><a>...</a><select class="x"></select><a>...</a><td><tr>
```

The problem is the last().prev() functions return the the object `<a>` which i suppouse come first the select one.

The nth-last-of-type(2) selector instead return an empty object.