# Get second last child td in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am able to get td's last child using this

```
$jq('#stripeTable > tbody > tr:nth-child('+(i+1)+') >td:last-child').text(colValues +" < "+ colValuesWithOverTime);
```

what to do and get second last child of td like i am getting last child using **td:last-child**

Comment: [nth-last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605785/select-second-to-last-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select second to last element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605785/select-second-to-last-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try **td:nth-last-child(2)**. This will select the 2nd child from the end.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, and congrats for first accepted answer. Your answer seems more suitable according to question context. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log($("td").last().prev().text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

use last and prev,

```
$("td").last().prev();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.eq()` function to get second last from jQuery array

```
var count = $('td').length;
var secondLast = $('td').eq(count - 2);
```